# Azure Functions: how to efficiently send batch of messages to Service Bus using bindings?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm working with Azure Functions 2.0 and trying to send a collection of messages to Azure Service Bus Topic. Currently I'm using `IAsyncCollector<T>` as output binding :

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static async Task MyFunction([ServiceBus(MyTopicName, EntityType.Topic, Connection = ServiceBusConnection) outTopic])
{
    var messages = await GetMessages();
    foreach(var message in messages)
    {
        await outTopic.AddAsync(message);
    }
}
```

Such approach is pretty convenient (declarative code, no boilterplate) but brings one significant issue: for large number of messages the performance is unacceptable. Is there any other recommended way to work with large batches that need to be sent to Azure Service Bus ?

Comment: Not sure what optimizations you have tried, but there are some best practices here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements

Comment: @MatthewEvans thank you for your response, I'm aware of that but ideally I would like to send messages in a batch using Azure Function bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a known issue in using IAsyncCollector with ServiceBus (and other services.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/921

See first response re ordering and this :

> This is easy when if we only send a small number of rows via
>   IAsyncCollector because we could just buffer in -memory and force an
>   ordering. But it’s prohibitive if we send huge payloads.